# rails 4 eager loading heavy association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an association between rails models.

There are three models which describe `product` properties:

`Property` is associating the models, each property has a name and value.

```
class Property < AR::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :property_name
  belongs_to :property_value

class PropertyName < AR::Base
  has_many :properties
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

class PropertyValue < AR::Base
  has_many :properties
  validates :value, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

After searching via [thinking-sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/) I get facets - property_values id & property_names id collections.

Using that result, I then try to find all properties for current list of `products` (to continue to filter those search results).

In the controller I use:

```
@property_names = PropertyName
  .where(id: property_name_ids)
  .includes(:property_values).where('property_values.id IN (?)', property_value_ids)
```

My view:

```
- @property_names.each do |property_name|
  h4 = property_name.name
  - property_name.property_values.pluck(:value).uniq.each do |property_value|
    = check_box_tag ...
    = label_tag ...
```

So, eager load does not work. Rails generate a lot of (n+1) queries for the database. What's going wrong? Why includes don't work?

Comment: Not regarding to your question.You can re-factor your `code`. `PropertyName` and `PropertyValue` are much looked like  `attributes` in `Property` rather being `separate models`.To me this looked rather inappropriate.

Comment: @Pavan yes, it can be a string. But thinking-sphinx need it to be a model association =)

Comment: I edited your question heavily to try to clarify the content.  I am still having a hard time understanding exactly what you're trying to say with your last paragraph.  Could you take a few moments and update it for us?  I think it would help you get an answer more quickly.

Comment: ok. Please wait for a short time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by me.

First of all, add a association `has_many :property_values, -> { uniq }, through: :properties` at property_names.

After that, I use this query:

```
  @property_names = PropertyName.where(id: property_name_ids).where.not(name: PropertyName.description)
    .includes(:property_values).where(property_values: { id: property_value_ids }).order('property_values.value')
```

All works!

Comment: .where(property_values: { id: property_value_ids }) this save my live. In my case the condition got always applied to the wrong model.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be including an association which is not defined, as `PropertyName` doesn't have the a 'property_values' relation defined.

You may want to do something like:

```
 PropertyName.includes(properties: :property_value)
```

Comment: No, it don't work. Or, maybe, I need to specify something at views?

Comment: Nope, nothing extra to specify in views. Except you can change the way how you iterate through records and prepare your collection. In this case I would try to change the query to the database, so it would return unique property_values, grouped by property_names. This way your collection would resemble more what you're doing with it in a view layer and you would get rid of N+1 queries for sure.

Comment: I get that query at result:

      `@property_names = PropertyName.includes(properties: :property_value).where(property_values: { id: @property_value_ids }).where(id: property_name_ids).where.not(name: propertyName.description).references(:properties)`

In views I write `- @property_names.each do |p_n| ... p_n.property_values.each do ...` and get the n+1 query! How can I avoid that?

Comment: Yes, I can see that in your original post. And my suggestion is to change the query to the database, so it would return unique property_values, grouped by property_names. Something along `PropertyValue.select('distinct property_values.*').joins('your property names').where('your conditions').group('properties.name')`. Then you iterate over groups taking the name out of it, and building your checkboxes by associated group contents.

Comment: I reasonably catch an error: `ERROR: column properties.name does not exist` because there isn't a column `name` in `properties` table. Else question: what do you mean by `joins('your property names')`? Need I pass a variable which get property_names or just use `joins(:property_names)`??

Comment: I meant "#{PropertyName.table_name}.name". As for a join, you just need to write a proper sql code, which will join your associations. Remember, your starting from `PropertyValue`.

Comment: Can you write an example of that query?